# Android Permissions System Deny Button

Tags: android, alertdialog

Estoy intentando integrar el sistema de permisos de android 6 en adelante. EL Objetivo es forzar al usuario a aceptar los permisos para poder usar la app. En el juego CSR Racing lo hacen ocultando en el System dialog de permisos el botón rechazar, pero no consigo acceder a este dialogo o hallar la forma de ocultarlo

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Arva una pregunta, que OS especificamente tiene tu dispositivo? puede ser un detalle especifico del OS, pero ocultar el boton cancelar definitivamente no se puede.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android 6.0+ :

> EL Objetivo es forzar al usuario a aceptar los permisos para poder
> usar la app.

**Esto no se permite, no puedes forzar al usuario a que acepte los permisos que requiere tu aplicación para funcionar correctamente.**

Lo que puedes realizar es detectar si tiene o no el permiso, sugerir aceptar el permiso y mostrar el dialogo.

En el caso de la aplicación que mencionas inicialmente muestra una ventana para sugerir que debes aceptar los permisos requeridos por la aplicación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente va requiriendo uno a uno :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si es que alguno o varios de ellos no los aceptaste muestra este dialogo volviendo a sugerir aceptarlos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> - Como nota importante, **el sistema operativo Android 6.0.1 tiene un bug** el cual en ocasiones muestra únicamente el botón permitir, y este en ocasiones no
>   tiene funcionalidad.

#### No existe forma en que puedas ocultar el botón "Rechazar" / "Deny".

Comment: ¿Cómo lo hacen los de CSR Racing entonces? Quizá muestran una imagen en blanco encima? Muy curioso. Aún así confirmo lo que comenta Elenasys, no se puede :).

Comment: @MiquelColl estoy instalando para revisar lo que comentan, definitivamente no se puede, te comento también que en Android 6.0.1 existe un bug el cual solo muestra el boton "permitir" pero no ejecuta nada.

Comment: ¡Di la verdad! ¡Vas a jugar! ¡Excusaaas! Yo ya me lo he instalado y no me ha aparecido así. Y sí, estoy jugando.

Comment: jeje casi no juego, me gustan pero no hay tiempo.  Agregue más info a mi respuesta

Comment: @Elanasys muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Estabamos algo confusos con este sistema :) Un saludo!!

Comment: Hola amigo en version de OS obtuviste este dialogo  sin boton? Saludos.